# Apache + asp.net mvc +linux

Tags: c#, linux, apache, asp.net-mvc, mono

Нужно опубликовать сайт на сервере где стоит линукс так как деплоинг сайта на виндовс стоит очень дорого. Какое програмное обеспечение нужно поставить на Linux(Debian) чтобы сервер Apache заработал разом с ASP.NET MVC сайтом?

Comment: .net framework не забудьте поставить на линукс, в общем unreal

Comment: Я может что-то не знаю, но вроде бы это на данный момент невозможно.

Comment: возможно при использовании .net core. Проблема в том, что если у Вас уже написанный проект - придется переносить